# Cannot use nova through curl, Authentication required

Tags: ubuntu, curl, cloud, openstack, openstack-nova

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and running openstack, I have set the enviroment variables for nova-api to work from command line i.e. **nova list** , **nova flavor-list**  **etc** are working perfectly, but when I try to use curl:

```
curl -i  http://192.168.1.130:8774/v2/f0c12be83d214d8a9d87ae731dd81ec1/images/detail -X
GET -H "X-Auth-Project-Id: admin" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -
H"Accept:application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: XXXXX"
```

the **Response** is:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Www-Authenticate: Keystone uri='http://192.168.1.130:35357'
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 23
Date: Sat, 19 Oct 2013 12:13:05 GMT
Authentication required
```

Envs are:

```
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=openstack
export OS_AUTH_URL=http:192.168.1.130:35357/v2.0
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

CURL will not fetch your openstack auth creds from the environment. 
The login credentials in your Envs **are only for use with the OpenStack command-line tools.**

Answer (score 0):

I hope you had solved the problem but just in case you didn't. Your question says something like `"X-Auth-Token: XXXXX"`.

You first have the get that token by authenticating with keystone using your username and password. Then use the token in your curl command.

[This](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html#id3) is how you do it.